# Manga where a girl and a bat vampire fall in love

Tags: story-identification, manga, vampire, animals

I'm looking for a manga where there is a human girl who is taking care of animals in a club at her school. She meets a guy who is a bat and then transforms into a vampire. He can fly. Eventually, the girl meets more animals that turn into humans with supernatural characteristics.

In the end, the girl is known to be Eve, and only Adam can drink her blood.